# Change bundle identifier in Xcode 8 – consequences for push notifications, Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, xcode8

I want to change the bundle identifier in Xcode 8, but I'm not sure about the consequences for doing so. I have a Firebase project and Apple push notifications that are both connected to the old bundle identifier.

I tried changing the bundle identifier under Target > General, and tried to send a notification from Firebase, which worked, even though both Firebase and the certificate in developer.apple.com referenced the old bundle identifier. Should I generate new certificates? What is the best course of action to avoid messing up anything?

I have also tried Googling around for changing the bundle identifier, but they only show how to do it in Xcode, but not what you should do if you also dabble with push notifications and/or Firebase.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push notifications basically works on the basis of your certificates.

1.Push certificates - uploaded on server to send push notifications to devices. 2.Development/Distribution certificates - used by app.

So both of them nowhere linked to bundle id if you try to create a new certificate.

While creating provisioning profile it is required to have add an app id & device ids so that an app can be installed on provisioned devices

Comment: What do you mean by "So both of them nowhere linked to bundle id if you try to create a new certificate."?

Comment: When we create a CSR & upload it on dev portal to generate certificate,we don't need to mention bundle id.
In your case ,if you have created new bundle id then you must have new /updated provisioning profile for that bundle id & must have selected available certificates which associate your app with same certificates again.

Comment: That's great eirikvaa !